# Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`History`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am actually building a tic tac toe. But this error is not actually letting me update history. As I am following a tutorial on skillshare.com and I did the same as he does. But still getting error. I am a beginner in React. And I use a nano-react npm project for creating this project.
This is App.js:

```
import React , {useState} from "react";
import Board from "./components/Board"
import History from "./components/History"
import {calculateWinner} from './support'
import StatusMessage from './components/StatusMessage'
import './styles/root.scss'

const NEW_GAME = [
  {
    board: Array(9).fill(null),
    isXNext : true
  }
]
const App = () => {

  const [history, setHistory] = useState(NEW_GAME);
  const [currentMove, setCurrentMove] = useState(0);

  const current = history[currentMove];

  const {winner , winningSquare} = calculateWinner(current.board);
  
  const clickHandleFunction = (position) => {
      if (current.board[position] || winner) {
          return;
      }

      setHistory((prev) => {
        const last = prev[prev.length-1];

          const newBoard =  last.board.map((square, pos) => {
              if (pos === position) {
                  return last.isXNext ? 'X' : '0';
              }
              return square;
          });
          return prev.concat({board: newBoard, isXNext : !last.isXNext})
      });

      setCurrentMove(prev => prev +1);
  };

  const moveTo = (move) => {
    setCurrentMove(move);
  }

  const onNewGame  = () => {
    setHistory(NEW_GAME);
    setCurrentMove(0);
  }

  return(
    <div className="app">
      <h1>TIC TAC TOE</h1>
      <StatusMessage winner ={winner} current ={current}/>
      <Board board = {current.board} clickHandleFunction = {clickHandleFunction} winningSquare = {winningSquare}/>
      <button type="button" onClick = {onNewGame}>Start New Game</button>
      <History history={history} moveTo = {moveTo} currentMove = {currentMove} />
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

And It is my History.js:

```
import React from 'react.'

function History({history, moveTo, currentMove}) {
    return (
        <ul>
            {
                history.map((_, move) => {
                    return( <li key={move}> <button style={{
                        fontWeight: move === currentMove ? 'bold' : 'normal'
                    }} type="button" onClick = {moveTo(move)} > 
                        {move === 0 ? 'Go to game start!': `Gove to move #${move}`} </button> </li> );
                })
            }   
        </ul>
    )
}

export default History
```

[image: Full Error image with Stack Trace]

Comment: Please give me a code sandbox to run the app

Comment: @ChanghoonLee https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-mirzakhani-nm7kp?file=/src/components/Board.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in `History.js`:

```
onClick={moveTo(move)}
```

You need to provide a function in the `onClick` prop. Instead, you are *calling* the `moveTo` function and passing its return value as the `onClick` prop.

Due to this, whenever React renders the History component, it also inadvertently calls the `moveTo` function which triggers an update in the App component. This is what the error says - can't update another component while rendering a component.

To fix this, change `moveTo(move)` to `() => moveTo(move)`. Now you pass a function into `onClick` that will call the `moveTo` function when the user clicks. Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-frog-tcyxm?file=/src/components/History.js

Answer (score 0):

In **React Navigation** move the `setParams` and `setOptions` inside method `componentDidMount()` in class components or in `useEffects()` hook in functional components.