# Passing state from child to parent dependent on counter

Tags: reactjs

I am using React + Styled Components. I'd like to achieve different display of item depending on state value. ItemsList contain list of Item (parent component). Item has Counter (child component):

```
export default function ItemsList() {
const quantity = useQuantity;

const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState(false)

return (
    <div style={{display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", justifyContent: "space-around"}}>
        {questsData.map(item => {
                return(
                    <Container>
                        <Item>
                            {isCompleted? <p style={{color: "white"}}>yes</p> : <p style={{color: "white"}}>no</p>}
                            <Item.ImageWrapper>
                                <Item.Image src={item.img}/>
                            </Item.ImageWrapper>
                            <Item.Tracker>
                                <Counter quantity={quantity} neededValue={item.quest} setIsCompleted={setIsCompleted} />
                            </Item.Tracker>
                        </Item>
                    </Container>
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
)}
```

Counter:

```
import useQuantity from "../Hooks/useQuantity"

export const Counter = ({ neededValue, setIsCompleted }) => {
const quantity = useQuantity()

const decrement = () => {
   quantity.setValue(quantity.value - 1);
};

const increment = () => {
  quantity.setValue(quantity.value + 1);
};

return (
  <>
    <button onClick={decrement} disabled={quantity.value === 0} style={{color: "#9a8866", backgroundColor: "inherit", border: "1px solid #9a8866"}}> - </button>
    <span style={{padding: "10px", color: "#9a8866"}}>
      {quantity.value} / {neededValue}
      {quantity.value === neededValue? setIsCompleted(true): setIsCompleted(false)}
    </span>
    <button onClick={increment} disabled={quantity.value === neededValue} style={{color: "#9a8866", backgroundColor: "inherit", border: "1px solid #9a8866"}}> + </button>
  </>
  );
};

export default Counter
```

Could you please let me know why setIsCompleted does not change state upon expression? It supposed to check if current value is equal required. If it is it should return true, otherwise it should return false

PS: Sorry about some in-line styling, I want to finish logic before I convert it all to styled components.

PS2: useQuantity is just simple hook to create separate state for each counter but if it's needed I can include it's code as well

Comment: Check the last item of `questsData` is `quantity.value === neededValue` equal?

Comment: Initially none of them are. Items quantity.value === neededValue is equal only when I press increment button enough times (could be 1-10 depending on item data)

Comment: You are passing quantity to <Counter /> as a prop but ignore it and get it from useQuantity() hook.

Comment: I pass it as whole hook so incrementing and decrementing is available in each Counter component. I've managed to make comparison which is working in Counter but it's not passing back to Parent (Item Component)

Comment: try calling `quantity.value === neededValue? setIsCompleted(true): setIsCompleted(false)` inside `increment` function and call `increment` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67815785/13405106)

Comment: Usama it didn't worked :/